# Python Pandas: Create DataFrame Fast

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function `some_function` that delivers a row that should be appended to a Pandas DataFrame.

The following code fulfills this task, but is very slow.

How can this be done faster?

```
import pandas as pd

def get_row(runner):
    row = some_function(runner)
    return row

mycolumns = ['A', 'B']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=mycolumns)
for runner in range(10000):
    df.loc[len(df)] = get_row(runner)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need create list of lists or tuples first and then pass to `DataFrame` constructor only once:

```
def get_row(runner):
    row = some_function(runner)
    return row

L = [get_row(runner) for runner in range(10000)]
mycolumns = ['A', 'B']
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=mycolumns)
```

Comment: `concat` not, because it should be slowier.